# CesiumJS not displaying globe with image

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to display a heatmap over the globe in Cesium but the globe isn't even showing up on the screen, only the background is.  I looked in the network part of google chrome and it shows the actual image I need being loaded from the server.

```html
<script>
        var count=0;
        var viewer = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');
        var layers = viewer.scene.imageryLayers;
        var imageArray = <?php echo json_encode($images) ?>// PARSING PHP ARRAY INTO JAVASCIPT
        alert(imageArray[0]);
        var date;var name='HeatMap-2006-01-16.png'; //FOR INITAL PAGE LOAD

        loadCesium();

        function loadCesium()
        {
            //Cesium Active Window
            layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider({
                url : 'images/'.concat(name),
                rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
            }));
        }
        function overlayChange()
        {
            name = imageArray[count];
            for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
            {
                if(name.charAt(i)=="-")
                {
                    date = name.substring(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            loadCesium();
            count = count + 1;
        }
        function overlayChangeBack()
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                count = 39;
                name = 'HeatMap';
                name = name.concat(count.toString());

                loadCesium();
            }
            else
            {
                name = 'HeatMap';
                count=count-1;
                name = name.concat(count.toString());

                loadCesium();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Right now I'm just trying to display the name variable('HeatMap-2006-01-16.png') for the initial image but it's not displaying.  No image I try to put instead displays either so it's definitely an issue with cesium.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this fixed it because I've had it working without this statement but when declaring the cesiumContainer in the variable viewer, you have to set it as this:

```
            var viewer = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer', {
            imageryProvider : new Cesium.ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider({
                url : 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer'
            }),
            baseLayerPicker : false
        });
```

Comment: Since you're controlling the imagery layers manually, turning off the `baseLayerPicker` seems like the right thing to do.  Otherwise your own code will be fighting with the UI widget for control over the displayed imagery layers.